# Yii 2 Add Panels on Website Home Page

Tags: php, panel, yii2

We are currently developing a somewhat an accounting system and I want that when user successfully logs in, he/she will be redirected to a page that would look like this (not exactly):

[image: Panels of different modules of the system]
Panels of different modules of the system.

If you take a look at WaveApps dashboard, it looks like this:
[image: WaveApps Dashboard]
They don't basically implement paneling. I just want you to get my point.

I want that the first thing that user will able to see after logging in is the "dashboard" of the system (just like after logging in in WaveApps).

I want to know how to put something like, for example in the first picture, the Calendar **panel** (is 'panel' even the right term? that 'panel' though is collapsible). Those panels we see in the first picture. How do we implement that in Yii 2? **What code do I use?** I haven't tried anything since I can't find one on any of my Google searches.

Comment: What's the exact problem / question?

Comment: How do I put those panels on my homepage? That first photo is implemented using Yii 1.

Comment: Please be more precise with your questions. In its current formulation it can be closed / deleted. Where exactly you stuck? What you have already tried?

Comment: Did you check Bootstrap 3 panels? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: Thanks. But how do I load/render a page inside that panel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71061/discussion-between-arogachev-and-kaynewilder).